# A custom sort before fetching the result from the DB

Tags: java, mongodb

I am using the Java driver to find certain entries on MongoDB.
What I am trying to do is fetch from my database all entries that fall between a certain latitude, longitude, but fetch only the closest 20 results.
So lets say I have parameters lat = Latitude , lng = Longitude.

I want to do:

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("latitude", new BasicDBObject("$gte", Double.parseDouble(lat) - 0.1).append("$lte", Double.parseDouble(lat) + 0.1));
query.put("longitude", new BasicDBObject("$gte", Double.parseDouble(lng) - 0.1).append("$lte", Double.parseDouble(lng) + 0.1));
db.find(query).limit(20).sort(???)...
```

The issues with the normal sort is that it does only ascending/descending order of a specific field, and it does not offer a more complex sort, such as: (lat+lng) for instance.

Furthermore, I need the sort to be done before it is fetched, as I want the closest 20 results from all the database, and not fetch 20 results that fit the query, and then only after they are fetched, sort them out.

Does anyone have any clue how to do this?

Comment: You cannot do this yet, edit: geonear queries is what your looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$geoNear` ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/geoNear/ ) should actually sort by closest first before returning.

A more general link for reference is: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/nav-geospatial/

Comment: Just a small query, do you know what input I give the geoNear command? I have two parameters lat/lng , but it seems it wants only one input. Do I concatenate both of them to one string with a comma? Or maybe its a list of 2 doubles? Any idea?

Comment: @Yarneo It requires a geospatial index and stuff, basically all of the geo spatial queries you are doing actually come built into MongoDB, you can read: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/